# JAX-RS using Eclipse

Tags: jax-rs

i am trying to create a JAX-RS web service in eclipse. i followed this http://www.vogella.com/articles/REST/article.html link. and my localhost threw these as my status report

HTTP Status 500:

```
type Exception report

message 

description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception 

javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet Jersey REST Service threw exception
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:46
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:562)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:395)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:250)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:188)
    

org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:166)
        org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:302)
        java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)


root cause 

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/objectweb/asm/ClassVisitor
    com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig.init(ScanningResourceConfig.java:79)
    com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig.init(PackagesResourceConfig.java:104)
    com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig.<init>(PackagesResourceConfig.java:78)
    com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig.<init>(PackagesResourceConfig.java:89)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.createResourceConfig(WebComponent.java:700)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.createResourceConfig(WebComponent.java:678)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:203)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:374)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:557)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:462)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:562)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:395)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:250)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:188)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:166)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:302)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

root cause 

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1676)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1521)
    com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig.init(ScanningResourceConfig.java:79)
    com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig.init(PackagesResourceConfig.java:104)
    com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig.<init>(PackagesResourceConfig.java:78)
    com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig.<init>(PackagesResourceConfig.java:89)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.createResourceConfig(WebComponent.java:700)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.createResourceConfig(WebComponent.java:678)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:203)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:374)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:557)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:462)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:562)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:395)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:250)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:188)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:166)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:302)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Note: the full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.12 logs.

I included all the jars, and still I am not able to hit the point of error.

Answer (score 1):

I just found the answer in case somebody else runs into the same pb: I installed jersey from the bundle. But the bundle is lacking asm lib. So I downloaded the zip jersey instead which contains the asm lib and it worked. :)

Answer (score 0):

I am also getting the same Error that is related to `ClassVisitor` of ASM library.

I found a solution by adding `asm-3.1.jar` for jersey 1.17.1 version that is available from  [this link](http://jersey.java.net/download.html) .

That solved the above error for me.